# Remote Port Forwarding on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, portforwarding

I just saw this blog about hosting Minecraft on OpenShift and I'd like to give it a try.

My only concern is the port forwarding.  For the other players that I would invite, setting up a local port forward would be too complex.

How can I forward the ports on the server so that can just enter a simple TLD instead?  Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want everyone to be able to access the minecraft server it is quite involved, you need everyone to sign up for an openshift account, add their accounts to your domain, and then have everyone do the port forward.

If you don't want to do that, you basically have to run something on another server where you had full access and run the port forward and tie them to publicly available ports.